# UK Visa Refusal V4.2 Freelancer / Married / Permanent EU Resident

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, filipino-citizens

Over the summer 2020 a friend from the UK visited myself and my husband in Greece for a few weeks. The friend in trying to repay the favour has offered me the opportunity to visit her and her husband in the UK. We recently applied for a visa but it was refused under V4.2 (basically because I haven't worked in 2020 because of Covid).

- I am a permanent Greek resident (Originally from Philippines)
- I am a freelance film maker who travels for work (normally), 2019 bank statements would show regular good income however because the jobs I get sent on are all over Europe / UAE I haven't had any work in 2020.
- I am married to Greek man who earns a good salary in Greece as an engineer. (He cant travel with me for reasons I wont bore you with)
- The friend I am visiting (my sponsor) owns her own business and has more than sufficient funds in her bank to support me in the UK.

In my first application we didn't really state or elaborate much on my freelance work or even the fact that I am married to an EU citizen who has obviously been the main earner in the house since I haven't been able to work due to Covid.

So, I guess my question is, if I was to apply again and elaborate into further detail about my life / work would I realistically have a chance and being granted a visa or not..?

Thanks a million for any advice / insight you can give.

Comment: It's possible that some of the advice in [this umbrella question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/92121/39667) will be relevant to you.

Comment: @L Perez When are you planning to travel and for how long? A timetable for meaningful relaxation of the current Covid restrictions in the UK is still unclear and they could well be in place for several months at least. It would probably help you get an answer if you posted details of the refusal letter with personal info blanked out

Comment: @Traveller yes, totally agree. We did explain in the application that the plan was for 2 weeks in March but our plans were totally flexible due to Covid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: Usually, the advice is to post the refusal letter (with personal data blacked out) as these tend to present the concerns the officers had quite precisely. However, most V 4.2 will fall into the linked dupe’s responsibility.